# Converting patterns to hyperlinks

Tags: vba, ms-word, hyperlink, wildcard

I'm trying to replace every instance of a pattern with a hyperlink derived from the pattern.

The pattern is of the form 123 WORD 4568, where the WORD is always the same but the numbers (and quantity of numbers) changes. E.g. 1948 WORD 12, 231 WORD 3948, 92 WORD 1029.

The hyperlink depends on the number, for 1948 WORD 12 it's something like [www.word.com/1948/12.html](http://www.word.com/1948/12.html)

Using wildcards, I can find all instances of the pattern and replace them with a hyperlink to just word.com:

```vb
Sub InsertLinksTB()

    Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range

    With Rng.Find
        SearchString = "[0-9]{1,9} WORD [0-9]{1,9}"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        Do While .Execute(findText:=SearchString, Forward:=False) = True
            Link = "www.word.com"

            ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Rng, _
            Address:=Link, _
            SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=Rng.Text
            Rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

I can't figure out what to do with SubAddress to generate the full hyperlink for each instance of the pattern, given the wildcards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pattern is always the same, you can use the `Split` function to get the elements of the string and construct the link.

```
Sub InsertLinksTB()

    Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range

    With Rng.Find
        SearchString = "[0-9]{1,9} WORD [0-9]{1,9}"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        Do While .Execute(findText:=SearchString, Forward:=False) = True
            Link = "www.word.com/" & Split(Rng.Text, " ")(0) & "/" & Split(Rng.Text, " ")(2) & ".html"
            
            ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Rng, _
                Address:=Link, _
                SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=Rng.Text
            Rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This works perfectly. Really appreciate your help

Comment: @xanadu246 please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers